# Find the area enclosed by the curves $x = 0$, $y = 3$ and $y = \sqrt{x}$.

Tags: calculus

Here is my attempt:

Since $y=\sqrt{x}$ and $y=3$, then $x=9$. Finally I tried to integrate the function $3-\sqrt{x}$ at $x=9$ and $x=0$. I got $9$ as my answer. Please correct me if I'm wrong, thanks!

Comment: It looks completely correct.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Your work is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.

---

You could also integrate $\mathrm{d}y$. $$y= \sqrt{x} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad x = y^2$$

So we can integrate $y^2$ from $y=0$ to $y=3$:

$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^3 y^2 \,\mathrm{d}y$$

$$\frac{3^3}{3} - \frac{0^3}{3} = \boxed{9}$$